# Ember: how to fire observers when any Em.A inside an Em.Object change

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have something like

```
property: Em.Object.create(foo: Em.A([]), bar: Em.A([])),

onAnyArrayChange: function(){
//some code
}.observes('WHAT HERE??')
```

Thing is I don't want to explicitly say

```
.observes('property.foo.[]', 'property.bar.[]')
```

I'd love something like

```
.observes('property.EACH_KEY.[]')
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with the `@each` property.
See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#property__each

What you need to do is convert your `property` from an `Ember.Object` into an `Ember.ArrayProxy` like this:

```
property: Em.ArrayProxy.create({
  content: [
    Em.A([]), // used to be foo
    Em.A([]) // used to be bar
  ]
});
```

And now you can:

```
.observes('property.@each.[]')
```